# Go, to many arguments in call t.Execute

Tags: html, database, go, render

Im trying to render a template with values that I got from a table of a db.
The problem is that when I run the program I got errors. I dont know what Im doing wrong.

I started creating an estructure:

```
type App struct{
    Title string
    Author string
    Description string
}
```

I created a function to render the templates:

```
   func render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, data map[string]interface{}){
    tmpl = fmt.Sprintf("templates/%s", tmpl)
    t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl)
    if err != nil{
        log.Print("template parsing error: ", err)
    }
    err = t.Execute(w, data)
    if err != nil{
        log.Print("template executing error: ", err)
    }
}
```

Then, here I got the apps from the database and try to render them to the html.

```
func myappsHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request){
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres"," user=postgres dbname=lesson4 host=localhost password=1234 sslmode=disable")
    if err != nil{
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
        rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT title, author, description FROM apps
                                 WHERE title ILIKE $1
                                 OR author ILIKE $1
                                 OR description ILIKE $1`)
            defer rows.Close()

            apps := []App{}
            for rows.Next(){
                b := App{}
                err := rows.Scan(&b.Title, &b.Author, &b.Description)

                if err != nil{
                log.Fatal(err)
            }
                apps = append(apps, b)
            }

            render(w, "myapps.html", map[string]interface{}{"apps" : apps})

        db.Close()
}
```

My main function:

```
func main() {

    http.HandleFunc("/myapps", myappsHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

And this is myapps.html

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Título</th>
    <th>Imagen</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
  </tr>
{{ range .}}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ .Title }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Author }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Description }}</td>
    <td> <form action="/delete">
          <p class="navbar-form navbar-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button> </p>
       </form></td>
  </tr>
{{ end  }}
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `render` with three arguments even though you have declared that it only takes two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `render` function accepts a `http.ResponseWriter` and a `string`. You are trying to pass it a `http.ResponseWriter`, a `string` **and** a `[]App`.

The short answer is that you should change your function to accept a `map[string]interface` that you can pass to `ExecuteTemplate`. This is useful when you want to pass more than one thing to a template later.

```
func render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, data map[string]interface{}){
        tmpl = fmt.Sprintf("templates/%s", tmpl)
        t, err := template.ParseFiles(tmpl)
        if err != nil{
            log.Print("template parsing error: ", err)
        }
        // We pass our data map to the template
        err = t.Execute(w, data)
        if err != nil{
            log.Print("template executing error: ", err)
        }
    }
```

... and call it like so:

```
    render(w, "myapps.html", map[string]interface{}{
        "apps": apps
    })
```

The long answer is that:

- You are establishing a new database pool on every request. Not good! Create either a global pool (okay; `sql.DB` has locks) or by passing a `*sql.DB` to your handlers.
- You are re-parsing your templates on every request. This is slow and inefficient. Parse them once on start-up as per http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/#tmp_6
- You can write a shortcut for `map[string]interface{}` by writing out `type M map[string]interface{}`, which will allow you to instead write `render(w, "myapps.html", M{"apps": apps})`
- You should split your DB query out into its own function so you can re-use it elsewhere.
- [sqlx](http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/) can help you from having to `rows.Scan()` things yourself - it's a nice convenience wrapper around `database/sql`.

#### Updated

I've managed to compile your code (for the most part) on my machine, and don't have any panics. I suggest you read the whole stack trace, **including the bit above the nil pointer deference/memory address**, which may be something along the lines of "template parsing error" (is your filename correct?).

http://play.golang.org/p/QZ65eP-Aln (I've commented out the database stuff)

You *will* need to fix your templates to have `{{ range .apps }}`, however that won't be the source of the panic.

```
<html>
<body>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Título</th>
    <th>Imagen</th>
    <th>Descripción</th>
  </tr>
{{ range .apps }}
  <tr>
    <td>{{ .Title }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Author }}</td>
    <td>{{ .Description }}</td>
    <td> <form action="/delete">
          <p class="navbar-form navbar-right"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Borrar</button> </p>
       </form></td>
  </tr>
{{ end  }}
</table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When I run it show me multiple errors about invalid memory address, I updated my question with your code on "myapps".

Comment: What line does the first part of the stack trace refer to? It should reference a line in the files where your code above (likely) resides. You will need to diagnose where your code panics - I can't help if I can't match the stack trace to the right line.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand pretty good your question. What do you mean?

Comment: Post the output of the stack trace and the corresponding line in your file that it references.

Comment: The error is biggest than this: 2014/07/10 15:38:18 http: panic serving [::1]:49607: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference goroutine 20 [running]:
net/http.func·011()
        c:/go/src/pkg/net/http/server.go:1100 +0xbe
runtime.panic(0x71ee80, 0x9495a2)
        c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 +0x1d3
database/sql.(*Rows).Close(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
        c:/go/src/pkg/database/sql/sql.go:1609 +0x37
runtime.panic(0x71ee80, 0x9495a2)
        c:/go/src/pkg/runtime/panic.c:248 +0x1d3
database/sql.(*Rows).Next(0x0, 0x9512f8)
        c:/go/src/pkg/database/sql/sql.go:1536 +0x25

Comment: You're likely seeing that because a) you are opening database pools per-request and b) you are not calling db.Close() at the end of your function. But without the full stack trace that is only a guess as to the cause.

Comment: @devtreat I've updated my answer. Unfortunately, without the full stack trace (post it to http://play.golang.org - but posting in your question is **fine**) it's hard to help any further.

Comment: Which line of your code corresponds main.go, line 45?

Comment: This is the line : for rows.Next(){

Comment: You are not checking the error from db.Query before calling rows.Next()

Comment: You are right! Thank you very much!, One question, I get this error and dont load the values of the db :  there is no parameter $1

Comment: Because you need to pass it arguments - `db.Query("SELECT ... $1 ... $2 ... $3", title, author, description)` - you have to pass it a title, author and description to replace those values with when it runs.

Comment: But how I adapt my query to that struct of title, author and description? because Im calling in for row.Next() the structure.

Comment: You're *saving* the results into `b` struct (which is fine - don't change that). But you need to tell the database title/author/description to run the `ILIKE` against *first* so it can try to match against those values.

Comment: Then I should remove ILIKE and do a:  "Select title, author, description where title=$1 and author=$2 and description=$3", title, author, description? But from where I take the variables title, author and description? they are inside the struct func.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57154/discussion-between-elithrar-and-devtreat).